# Parse Dashboard - Why have multiple apps?

Tags: dashboard, parse-server

I followed Ray Wenderlich's excellent, and brand new, tutorial on setting up Parse Server and Parse Dashboard on Heroku.

[Migrating to Parse Server for Heroku](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128313/parse-server-tutorial)

When setting up Parse Dashboard, it says to edit the parse-dashboard-config.json file as follows:

```
{
"apps": [
{
"serverURL": "WHAT_GOES_HERE",
"appId": "shhh",
"masterKey": "shhh",
"javascriptKey": "shhh",
"restKey": "shhh",
"appName": "AppName-Heroku"
},
{
"serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
"appId": "shhh",
"masterKey": "shhh",
"appName": "AppName-Local"
}
]
}
```

The question is, why have two apps listed here? When I run the dashboard, my "localhost" app actually points to, and updates, the mlab db on heroku. 
The "heroku" app is empty, likely because I don't have the correct serverURL. What is the correct URL for this?

Comment: You specify 2 apps instances in the config files. That's why there are 2 apps listed. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two questions:

1. Why are there 2 apps listed in the config file?

This is because the tutorial demonstrates on how to **migrate** an existing app from Parse.com to your own Parse Server. The first app configuration points to the app on Parse.com as you can see by the API endpoint `https://api.parse.com/1` in the tutorial which you replaced by "what_goes_here". The second app configuration point to your self-hosted Parse Server instance that you have running on your system as you can see by the API endpoint `http://localhost:1337/parse`.

2. What is the correct URL for the property `serverURL`?

The API endpoint `https://api.parse.com/1` is the correct URL for your Parse.com hosted app, you must not change this URL, it is the same for every Parse.com customer. The API endpoint for your self-hosted Parse Server can vary depending on your system configuration but usually it is `http://localhost:1337/parse`.